# Pandas Auto Reverse Resample from Last Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, ohlc

This issue has been partially addressed elsewhere but I'm having difficulty finding a way to make this work with OHLC financial market data.

I want to take 5-minute data and resample it into 4-hour data with the assumption that new data arrives every 5 minutes. Thus, using a fixed base in the Pandas resample does not work properly for this.

The **last 4 hours** containing Open(first), High(max), Low(min), Close(last), needs to be **calculated from the last timestamp** in reverse; from the bottom of the dataframe up. If the last time stamp is 14:05, then the final 4-hour resampled bar in the dataset should be stamped 10:05; when data at 14:10 is processed, it should resample back to 10:10, etc.

I'm seeking a method that can *automatically* determine how to set resample parameters based on the *last timestamp* or other dynamic approach (as this will update automatically with newer data) and then resample accordingly.

This is the traditional resample method I'm currently using:

```
ohlc_dict = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}
df = df.resample('240T', base=21).agg(ohlc_dict).dropna()
```

Is there any way to achieve this resampling objective?

Comment: I'm afrait there's no such resampling method in pandas. The closest I've found to that is negatively offsetting `resample`'s `base` parameter: Say your last OHLC row is at 14:05, and your first was at 00:00. Doing `df.resample('240T', base=-114)` will get you a resampled index ending in ***10:06***. If you need ***10:05*** to be there instead of ***10:06***, you could do `base=-115` - but your last index value will then be ***14:05***; i.e. a 4h interval that only accounts for the last OHLC row. Not useful for your usecase.